# Hbase Column Qualifier Design

Tags: hbase

Would it be a good design to concatenate values in column qualifier name? For example, to record statewise, citywise product sale, State is append to the city qualifier name

Column Family: {Column Qualifier:Version:Value}
cf: {‘CA_SFO’: 1383859182496:10000}

Where cf: column family
"CA": State
"SFO": City
1383859182496: Version
10000: Product value

Thanks

Comment: My most common HBase comment/question: what are the data access patterns? :) Second question, what's the key?

Comment: Data will be access on RowKey+Filtered on one of values in Column qualifier name. Row Key is country name. For example, RowKey=Country and state in that country